# Como filtrar lo que busco en una bd con php y PDO por medio de condiciones

Tags: php, html, pdo

espero me puedan ayudar ya que tengo una problematica, tengo dos select el cual una selecciono la categoria y el otro el pais, lo que quiero es que por ejemplo si selecciono la categoria sin elegir pais me busque solo la categoria que elegi al igual que si solo elegi pais sin categoria solo me encuentre por pais.

AL igual que si el usuario elegi por ejemplo una categoria y un pais me busque en la BD todo las categorias que eligio en el pais seleccionado.

Por ejemplo:
selecciono informatica en mexico me busque todo acerca de esa categoria en Mexico y si elegi solo informatica me muestre todo sobre esa categoria en todos los lados donde haya.

Si elegi pais me busque solo en ese pais.

con ese if solo puedo buscar si eligo los dos y me funicona pero queiro hacer todo eso lo coemntado.

Saludos y gracias.

```html
if (isset($_GET['pais']) && ($_GET['categoria']) ){
$cate = $_GET['categoria'];
$pais = $_GET['pais'];
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM empleos WHERE categoria = :cate AND pais = :pai ORDER BY enc_id DESC LIMIT $page1,12";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM empleos WHERE categoria = :cate AND pais = :pai ORDER BY enc_id DESC";
$fromsearch = true;

$pais = "$pais";
$categoria = "$cate";
$title = "$categoria empleos en $pais";
}

else{
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM empleos ORDER BY enc_id DESC LIMIT $page1,12";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM empleos ORDER BY enc_id DESC";
$pais = "NULL";
$categoria = "NULL";
$title = "Lista de empleos";
}

<select class="form-control" name="categoria" >
<option value="">Selecciona tu categoria</option>
Datos aqui
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="pais" >
<option value="">Selecciona tu pais</option>
Datos aqui
</select>
```

Comment: Pero el estilo de consulta que estás implementando no es de `mysqli`, es de `PDO`. ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta `mysqli` en la pregunta?

Comment: Listo se me paso ya que ando tratando de que me orienten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ese tipo de consultas yo uso una variable vacía y la completo de acuerdo a la necesidad.

```
$sql="";
if($cate!=""){
  if($sql==""){
     $sql=" categoria='$cate'";
  }
  else{$sql=" AND categoria='$cate'";}
}
if($pais!=""){
  if($sql==""){
     $sql=" pais='$pais'";
  }
  else{$sql=" AND pais='$pais'";}
 }
```

y por último la incorporo a la consulta.

```
 "SELECT * FROM empleos WHERE $sql";
```

Espero te ayude mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, una pregunta en las comillas iria algo? o lo dejo vacio?

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo pude resolver mi hermano sale como yo quiero, muchos saludos a ti y a toda la comunidad.